# Google App Engine naked domain redirect - handle the GET request

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to develop an "twitter-like" application where users can showcase their artwork on a simple interface like twitter. Obviously I also want to provide a simple URL for each user (e.g domain.com/myuser) but I found that GAE doesn't allow naked domains anymore so I did a DNS redirect as per google docs http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hlrm=en-in&answer=61057 so when users type domain.com they are redirected to www.domain.com.
 The problem is that when they type domain.com/myuser they are redirected to www.domain.com too and the username is lost which is quite annoying so I would like to know if you can recommend me a feasible solution. 
 Should I catch the referrer URL to find what user was typed on the naked domain ? Is there any other solution ?

Comment: I tested the Google Apps based redirect (https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general?hl=en#naked_domain) today, and I find that both path info (`/foo/bar`) and query string (`?a=b`) are preserved correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How URL forwarding works depends on the provider. If your provider doesn't include the path when sending a redirect, you should find one who does - [zoneedit](http://zoneedit.com/), for instance.

Comment: Is there any plan to just start supporting naked URLs..? www is so '90s!

Comment: @Lipis Regardless of your feelings as to the fashionability of www, it's still the best way to do it - because it's the only way to delegate the resolution of a name to another server. The only way to reliably do 'naked' domains with the load balancing and failover that App Engine provides would be to have App Engine itself host your domain's DNS.

Answer (score 1):

These guys also offer a free service that merely redirects (domain) to www.(domain) when it's IP is listed as an A DNS entry. http://wwwizer.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your suggestion. I actually use Dyn .

Comment: I also noticed that now, as of some time around when I made that comment, Google Apps will redirect your naked domain under "Domain Settings" -> "Domain Names" you can enabled it for your primary domain only. They give you 4 IP addresses to use as A-records.